# Sorting names by their high scores

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I want to sort a list of names by their score.
What I have so far is

```
file = open("scores.txt", 'r')
for line in file:
    name = line.strip()
    print(name)
file.close()
```

I'm unsure how to sort them.

Here's the file contents:

```
Matthew, 13
Luke, 6
John, 3
Bobba, 4
```

What I want the output to be:

```
John 3
Bobba 4
Luke 6
Matthew 13
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `.split(',')` method to split a line into its separate parts, then use `int()` to convert the score to a number.  The `.sort()` method sorts a list in place, and the `key` tells it what to sort by.

```
scores = []
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split(',')
        score = int(score)
        scores.append((name, score))

scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])

for name, score in scores:
    print(name, score)
```

This will give you a list of tuples containing (name, score) pairs in sorted order.  If you want to print them out with a comma in between them (to keep it consistent) change the print to `print(name, score, sep=', ')`

The reading of the input file can also be expressed as one (big) line

```
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    scores = [(name, int(score)) for name, score in (line.split(',') for line in f)]
```

---

A brief explanation of the `key=`:

a lambda function is an anonymous function, that is, a function without a name.  You generally use these when you need a function only for a small operation.  `.sort` has an optional `key` keyword argument that takes a function and uses the return of that function in sorting the objects.

So this `lambda` could also be written as

```
def ret_score(pair):
    return pair[1]
```

And you could then write  `.sort(key=ret_score)`  but since we dont really need that function for anything else, its not necessary to declare it.  The lambda syntax is

```
lambda <arguments> : <return value>
```

So this lambda takes a pair, and returns the second element in it.  You can save a `lambda` and use it like a regular function if you wish.

```
>>> square = lambda x: x**2 # takes x, returns x squared
>>> square(3)
9
>>> square(6)
36
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so in prints out Vertically?Like-
John 3
Bobba 4
Luke 6
Matthew 13

Comment: @user2365677 yes I just added that

Comment: Just for information sake, ".sort(key=lambda s: s[1])"
i know of the .sort, what does lambda mean?
It does work, its what i wanted and thank you :)

Comment: @user2365677 I've added a quick explanation of `lambda` but it can be a strange thing to understand

Comment: @user2365677 np, i threw in one last thing on how to shorten the input file reading if you want to use it