# How do i sort a text file numerically highest to lowest?

Tags: python, sorting

So i have a text file containing names,scores and class in there
e.g.

```
= ('test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 1)
```

How can i sort it (text file) so that it sorts it numerically by the score?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should have an attempt at code when you post here.

Comment: I have tried all the codes on here=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting names by their high scores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632428/sorting-names-by-their-high-scores)

Comment: No i just tired that and it did not work. it said=ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 2):

First, read the file into a list of lists:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    list = []
    for line in file:
        list.append(line[1:-1].split(","))
```

Now you have something like this:

```
list == [['test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 3],
         ['test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 5],
         ['test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 1],
         ['test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 2]]
```

Then sort lists inside the list:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[4]))
```

This results in this sorted list:

```
list = [['test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 1],
        ['test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 2],
        ['test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 3],
        ['test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your edit, SuperBiasedMan! :)

Comment: There's a good explanation of `lambda` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17632482/6505499).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function as

```
sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key = lambda x : x[4] )
```

**Example**

```
>>> lines = [ ('test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 1),
            ('test', ' in class', '4', ' has got a score of', 4),
            ('test', ' in class', '5', ' has got a score of', 5),
            ('test', ' in class', '3', ' has got a score of', 3),
            ('test', ' in class', '2', ' has got a score of', 2) ]

>>> sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key = lambda x : x[4] )
>>> soted_lines
('test', ' in class', '1', ' has got a score of', 1)
('test', ' in class', '2', ' has got a score of', 2)
('test', ' in class', '3', ' has got a score of', 3)
('test', ' in class', '4', ' has got a score of', 4)
('test', ' in class', '5', ' has got a score of', 5)
```

Comment: Looks like you were 3 minutes later, with just about the same answer. There's a good explanation of `lambda` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17632482/6505499).