# Python: How do i sort integers in a text file into ascending and/or descending order?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a text file(data.txt) containing names and scores 1:1 i.e.:

```
Mike = 1\n John = 2\n Cam = 3\n
```

I want to sort the integers along with the corresponding name in ascending and descending order.

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    list = []
    for line in file:
        list.append(line[1:-1].split(","))
list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[4]))
```

Yes, i have done some research however it doesn't work, i was hoping one of you guys could help me fix the code above. I know i must convert the data within the text file into a list then sort the list then put write back to the text file, but i am not sure how.
Source: [How do i sort a text file numerically highest to lowest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323641/how-do-i-sort-a-text-file-numerically-highest-to-lowest)

Comment: Splitting on a comma (`,`) doesn't seem to make any sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, doing it in memory using the sorted() function.

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    sorted_data=sorted(file.readlines(), 
                       key=lambda item: int(item.rsplit('=',1)[-1].strip()))
```

sorted_data will then contain a list of the sorted rows.

Here it is:

open the file:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
```

Get all the lines of the file (as a list):

```
file.readlines()
```

For each line in the file, sorted() will numerically sort them based on the output of passing each line into the "key" function.

The "key" function takes a line, splits it by the "=" symbol, then takes the last part of that (the part after the = sign), strips any leading or trailing whitespace (.strip()) and returns the value cast to an integer (int) .

Sorted takes the lines and orders them using the numbers output by the key function.

Comment: what do i enter in filepath?

Comment: just ran it and it didnt sort the data :(

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?