# 2D list only sorting by the first digit

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

This 2 dimensional list contains name and score. I need it to sort in descending value from the 2nd column.

```
scores = "scores.txt"
highScores = list()   # place all your processed lines in here

with open(scores) as fin:
    for line in fin:
       lineParts = line.split(": ")
       if len(lineParts) > 1:
           lineParts[-1] = lineParts[-1].replace("\n", "")
           highScores.append(lineParts)   # sorting uses lists
    highScores.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
print(highScores)

with open('sorted.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in highScores:
        f.write(str(item) +"\n")
```

The inputs are:

```
test1: 5
test2: 6
test3: 1
test4: 2
gd: 0
hfh: 5
hr: 3
test: 0
rhyddh: 0
Marty: 5425
testet: 425
place: 84
to: 41
```

But the outputs are:

```
['place', '84']
['test2', '6']
['Marty', '5425']
['test1', '5']
['hfh', '5']
['testet', '425']
['to', '41']
['hr', '3']
['test4', '2']
['test3', '1']
['gd', '0']
['test', '0']
['rhyddh', '0']
```

As seen, it sorts the column only by the first digit. How can I fix this?

Comment: That is because you are sorting integers that are of type string and you aren't actually sorting by type int. Change the second item to `int` explicitly then sort.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631581/python-how-do-i-sort-integers-in-a-text-file-into-ascending-and-or-descending-o

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert strings to integers in your sort key:

```
highScores.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Otherwise, as you found, your sort will be processed one character at a time, as you would expect with a string.